# How to permanently change the video player HUD to show time remaining?

Tags: safari, video, quicktime

In macOS Monterey (12.6.1) the native video player HUD shows two times -- time elapsed on the left of the progress bar, and total video time on the right. If one clicks the total time, the one on the right, it changes to show how much time is remaining.

> [image: before]
> *By default the video HUD tells me how long the video is, 11 seconds in this screenshot*

> [image: after]
> *After clicking it changes to tell me how much time remains, 8 seconds in this screenshot*

How can I change this behavior, so my Mac's native video controls show time remaining by default?